# Handling importing libraries if not present at execution time

Tags: c, cocoa, shared-libraries, static-libraries

Beside my OS X app, I'm using an helper tool which runs with root permissions in /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools

I'm integration Hockey framework which resides in my bundle app.
Works well in the app, I try to integrate it in the helper tool.

As my helper tool don't know where to look for Hockey framework (and I don't want to use a .pkg installer), I'm trying to copy the framework in /Library/Frameworks

On first launch of my helper tool, framework is not yet present, and I'm already importing it.

How can I handle a conditional import of my library while it's been copied, the whole with the same helper tool?

Answer (score 0):

Your tool needs to use lazy binding, not launch-time binding (apple calls it dependent libraries vs. dynamically loaded libraries).

```
DLOPEN(3)
```

See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dlopen.3.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dlopen

If it returns null, the library isn't installed yet.